# Is there any better way to load php page fill with database object using javaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following JavaScript function is working as expected.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="row gy-4 justify-content-center">
                    <?php
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                                echo '<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">';
                                echo '<div class="gallery-item h-100">';
                                echo '<img src="' . $row['url_src'] . '" class="img-fluid" alt="404 Not Found">';
                                echo '<div class="gallery-links d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">';
                                echo '<a href="'. $row['url_src'] . '" title="" class="glightbox preview-link"><i class="bi bi-arrows-angle-expand"></i></a>';
                                //echo '<a href="'. $row['url_tar'] . '" class="details-link"><i class="bi bi-link-45deg"></i></a>';
                                echo '<a href=# onclick="javascript:loadpage(id)" id="'. $row['Name'] . '" class="details-link" ><i class="bi bi-link-45deg"></i></a>';
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '</div>';
                            }

                    ?>
                </div>
```

But following piece of code is keep showing Uncaught ReferenceError: loadpage is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM105 index.php:1:12)

```
function loadpage(ID) {
    //alert(ID);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Name: ID
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $variab = response;
            if ($variab == '1') {} else {}
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any reference link missing?

Looks like missing some basic understanding or mixing two things, will see how it goes when someone tried it before or have any link that can further investigate.

```js
**details.php**
$page_id = $_POST['Name'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $page_id . "` WHERE status='y'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0)
    {        
    echo "1";
    return (true);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "0";
    return (false);
    }
```

Comment: You have a strange mix of PHP and Javascript there.  The second snippet is Javascript, but the first snipped is a mix of the two that cannot possibly work.  Show us more of the PHP.

Comment: The second snippet won't show such an error, as `loadpage` is not called anywhere in the second snippet. Also, are you sure your problem is related to AJAX itself?

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I have updated PHP code.  I am trying to load details.php page from AJAX inside JavaScript function. The data will be filled from database table. and table name is in the POST request. Not sure how to do it. or any other better way.

Comment: Its still a weird mix - your echo statements should be wrapped in `<?php` and `?>` or `<?=` and `?>`. Your SQL query is _super unsafe_ and you will get hacked without proper sanitation. Use `PDO` instead when using PHP. Also _we don't know how you are outputting your needed code_.

Comment: Code is wrapped inside php tags. Also updated php code.

Comment: But how is your _second_ non-functioning piece of code included? In the same way? Because it should work, but since you just add it as "some js code" we can't really tell. It should work, so clearly there must be something else going on that we are not being shown right now.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, this includes the code itself and any explanation about the problem

Comment: You guys were really helpful. Advices and suggestions worked.